# Issues running my New Data on -Tweet Sentiment Analysis

Tags: python, machine-learning, twitter, scikit-learn, sentiment-analysis

So I've made a airline twitter sentiment analysis script using this as reference: https://github.com/sunilpankaj/Twitter-US-Airline-Sentiment/blob/master/Cleaning%20data%20and%20prediction.ipynb

It's been trained and optimized and I have around a 78.6% accuracy on the commonly used CrowdFlower airline twitter data set.

I now have a new set of recent tweets that have been processed to remove stopwords, other symbols, etc., and put into a .csv file.

It looks like this:

southwestairlin look oper agent appli sanfrancisco job
check job busi consult sale analyt southwestairlin dalla
sr citrix engin need dalla appli southwestairlin job
check job euc system engin southwestairlin dalla
southwestairlin look station administr denver appli job
new job open southwestairlin atlanta appear technician
southwestairlin hire train schedul dalla appli job
rt riski busi fli faa lower hire standard faa deltaairlin jetblu southwestairlin

Each new line represents a different tweet.

I now want to input this data into the classifier I already trained using the CrowdFlower dataset, have it identify the sentiment of the tweet and write the sentiments to a new .csv file similar to this:

Positive

Neutral

Neutral

Negative

How would I go about doing this? Sorry for the bad formatting, this is my first time posting. I can also post some code if it would help.

My entire code:
[Code Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OmMD.png)
[Code Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfR6S.png)

Comment: You will need to all the preprocessing that you did while you trained. That includes "Data Cleaning", stemming, stopwords removal, and then joining. (Basically all what you did in Code Part 1).

Comment: After that you need to `vect.transform()` (Not `fit_transform()`) on the same `vect` object that you called `fit_transform()` on (not a new one), and then finally use the transformed data in the `nb.predict()`. So while training you need to save these two objects :- `vect` and `nb`.

Comment: Also always post the code as text, so that others can copy it. You posted that as image which hinders and discourages others from helping because no one will write the whole thing from scratch.

Comment: So what I attempted to do was to:




`newtweets = pd.read_csv("SWProcessed.csv")`

`dataframe=newtweets.iloc[:,0]`

`newtweettransform = vect.fit_transform(dataframe.values.astype('U'))`

`prediction = nb.predict(newtweettransform)`


But then I get the error:
ValueError: Expected input with 8360 features, got 1610 instead.



after running the nb.predict() line with my transformed data.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a classifier object (nb = MultinomialNB() for example) that you have called the .fit() method on, you can just take the same reference to that object and call the predict method on it as follows:

```
predictions = nb.predict(new_features)
```

Once you have the predictions you have several options for putting them into a .csv file. If you are familiar with pandas dataframes you can do something like:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"predictions": predictions})
df.to_csv("predictions.csv")
```

Or if you are more familiar with numpy:

```
np.savetxt(predictions, "predictions.csv", delimiter=",")
```

Note: Pandas has significantly faster I/O than numpy, so I recommend it for large datasets

Comment: I guess my question really is: 
So how do I take the data in my .csv file, and get what you have labeled as "new_features"?

Comment: Oh, my apologies for misunderstanding. I recommend using the read_csv() function, that will load each features in your csv file into a dataframe. Then use the countVectorizer() method from the notebook in the github link you posted to change the  features into their numerical form, and that should leave you with the new_features object that can be used in the predict method.

Comment: https://ibb.co/jVeaXo
Lines 87-91 are my attempt to do what you suggested.
They give me the following error:
https://ibb.co/eiazso

Comment: So something in your data is different than what was used in that github link. Looks like you have a value (np.nan) somewhere in your data that the vect.fit_transform() method doesn't like. Try getting rid of all np.nan's in your data first.